# How I can set Chooser to show multiple type of intents?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-mediaplayer, intentfilter

I am trying to open a dailog for palyers that can steam a audio player.

I am doing this

```
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(finalPath), "audio/*");
List<ResolveInfo> intents = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);

if (intents != null && intents.size() > 0) {
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Player"));
}
```

I have one my own player written to play. I also want to show my player in the chooser dialog only when user is using my application. Mean I don't want to be play audios from outside of application when user try `intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(finalPath), "audio/*");` so I make my palyer activity like

```
<activity
    android:name=".player.MyAudioPlayer"
    android:label="My Player"
    android:screenOrientation="sensor"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:mimeType="audiomy/*"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**How I can show both of MIMI Type in one intent chooser?**
as when I as when I do

`intent.setype("audiomy/*");`

it skip other player and vice versa

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I'm facing the same issue in my current project.

Comment: No I did not find any solution

Answer (score -1):

Set your player's intent-filter to accept the same intent and it will appear in the list automatically.

Comment: Please read again: I don't want to be play audios from outside of application when any other user try intent.setType("audio/*");